# Run npm command in exact folder with powershell

Tags: powershell

i want to run npm command in each folder

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "desiredFolder" | ForEach-Object {&npm install}
```

Problem i am experiencing is that npm command runs from root folder where is script not from each folder from foreach. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Push-Location`/`Pop-Location` to drop in and out of the directory while installing:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "desiredFolder" | ForEach-Object { $_ |Push-Location; try{ &npm install }finally{ Pop-Location }}
```